# Is the following ring a prime/maximal ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Are the following statements true or false in rings $R \subset S$ with unity $1$?

1. If $I\vartriangleleft R$ is a prime ideal, then $\{ \sum_{i \in \mathbb N}r_is_i| r_i \in I, s_i \in S\}$ is a prime ideal of $S$.
2. If $I\vartriangleleft S$ is a maximal ideal, then $I\cap R$ is a maximal ideal of R.

The second statement is false and I have found a counterexample, but with R without unity: let $S=\mathbb Z$, $I=2\mathbb Z$ and $R=10\mathbb Z$. The first one, however, I don't have a clue wether this is true or false. So maybe a better counterexample for the second one and some help for the first one would be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd be sceptical about both....

Comment: Both have quite trivial counterexamples using just $\mathbb Z\subseteq\mathbb Q$.  If you have a counterexample, you should have included it: it counts as context.

Comment: Thanks, I have included it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are false. Let $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $S=\mathbb{Q}$. First, note that the only prime or maximal ideal of $S$ is $(0)$.

For (1), if $I=(p)\subset R$ then $p\cdot\frac{1}{p}=1$ is in the set $\{\sum r_i s_i\mid r_i\in I,s_i\in S\}$.

For (2), note that $(0)$ is not maximal in $R$.